# Position relative div hides position absolute div

Tags: css, position, css-position

I am basically `php` programmer and having only basic `css` knowledge. I am currently implementing a jquery slider whose `div` is

```
.flexslider {background: #fff; 
border: 4px solid #fff; 
position: relative; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-o-border-radius: 5px; 
border-radius: 5px; 
zoom: 1;
}
```

The corresponding HTML is:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="css/images/sliders/inacup_samoa.jpg" />
            <p class="flex-caption">Captions and cupcakes. Winning combination.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://flex.madebymufffin.com"><img src="css/images/sliders/inacup_pumpkin.jpg" /></a>
            <p class="flex-caption">This image is wrapped in a link!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="css/images/sliders/inacup_donut.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="css/images/sliders/inacup_vanilla.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Now I have jquery drop down menu too whose sub element css is :

```
#jsddm li ul
{   
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
margin-top:12px;
}
```

And the HTML :

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul id="jsddm">
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jQuery Plugin</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ajax Navigation</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Effect</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Slide Effect</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fade Effect</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Opacity Mode</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop Shadow</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Semitransparent</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Now the problem is , the child elements of the drop down menu hides after adding the div `<div class="flexslider">`. If I remove `position:relative;` from it the menu works fine but the slider div becomes wider and and the horizontal scroll bar appears ( but nothing appears in the additional scrolled area !, see reference image[image: after removing position from slider div] )

Comment: A fiddle will help, i can't understand from image.

Comment: I uploaded here : http://green.anjaybee.com/test/

Comment: Upload to jsfiddle.net so i can edit and answer you.

Comment: Have you try change it from relative to absolute?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W5Vpx/3/

Comment: `position:absolute` hides drop down menu, footer and container at top !

Comment: The only sulotion is to move the slider down or make it smaller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32126/discussion-between-nitish-and-yotam)